# VF Controller: SOQL Query - Invalid bind expression

Tags: apex, visualforce

When I add my `WHERE` clause on the last query I get the following error:

```
Invalid bind expression type of Account_Counselor__c does not match domain of foreign key
```

Part of controller code:

```
    public Id selectedHubId {get; set;}

    public list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> getOpenEnrollments(){

        List<Account_Counselor__c> cAccounts = new list<Account_Counselor__c>(
            [Select Id,Account__c FROM Account_Counselor__c WHERE Hub_Name__c = :selectedHubId]);

        List<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> OEs = new list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c>(
        [Select Account__c,Account__r.Name,Name,Type__c,OE_Type__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c
                                          FROM OE_Rollover_Spans__c
                                          WHERE Account__c IN :cAccounts]
        );

return OEs;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    public Id selectedHubId {get; set;}

    public list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> getOpenEnrollments(){

    List<string> whereList = new List<String>();

List<Account_Counselor__c> cAccounts = new list<Account_Counselor__c>(
                [Select Id,Account__c FROM Account_Counselor__c WHERE Hub_Name__c = :selectedHubId]);
    for(Account_Counselor__c cc:cAccounts ){
    whereList.add(cc.Account__c );
    }

            List<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> OEs = new list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c>(
            [Select Account__c,Account__r.Name,Name,Type__c,OE_Type__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c
                                              FROM OE_Rollover_Spans__c
                                              WHERE Account__c IN :whereList]
            );

    return OEs;
    }
```

Comment: Anurag, Just a quick note. While posting an answer always add problem solution with few words so that user know what he did wrong with his code.

Comment: sure @Himanshu, I'll keep that in mind for sure. Thank you